# Time zone Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, heroku, timezone

So when I run the Heroku Rails Console and I do:

```
irb(main):005:0> Time.zone
=> (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
```

And when I do:

```
 irb(main):004:0> Time.now
    => 2013-07-20 16:00:38 +0000
```

Which is not "true", because the current PDT time is 9:00. What can be happening here? I want to make sure that both Time and DateTime objects will be in PDT, because I am using a `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(my_date)` and I want to make sure that this is PDT related.

Comment: `Time.zone.now` => `Sat, 20 Jul 2013 09:10:25 PDT -07:00` try that on Heroku console and see if you get similar result

Comment: house9 awesome. However, how could I do the same with DateTime? I need to set a specific date with specific time in that particular Zone, and DateTime.zone doesn't exist. Also, I need to make sure that distance_of_time_in_words_to_now is actually taking into account the set Zone.

Comment: I would assume `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now` uses Time.zone.now - but if you are concerned about it use `distance_of_time_in_words(Time.zone.now, my_date)` instead - if you set the current thread to your target timezone usually things 'just work' see see http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised - and for your DateTime try using `in_time_zone` - not sure if that will be needed but - `DateTime.parse("2013-07-20 10:00:00").in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')`

Comment: For more info and to understand why/how this all works, see `Time`, `TimeZone` and `TimeWithZone` in Rails `ActiveSupport`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Time.zone` returns the rails time zone (which in theory can be changed as much as you want -  a different one for each user for example).

To get the time in that zone, do

```
Time.zone.now
```

instead of

```
Time.now
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to offset your Heroku timezone with:

```
heroku config:add TZ=America/Los_Angeles
```

Then run Time.now again.

Comment: heroku config:add TZ=America/Los_Angeles, can u tell me where to add this in Node.js?
......................................
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715072/how-to-set-a-time-zone-for-heroku/44715172?noredirect=1#comment76412658_44715172