# How to set a time zone for Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, time, timezone

I have written a Node.js server to run on Heroku (Global). Everything works fine in my localhost, but as Heroku's time zone is UTC my function now runs incorrectly. Can someone please help me set a default time zone?

Here is my code:

```
router.get('/year/:yyear/:mmonth/:ddate/:hhours/:mminute/:sseconds/:fireTitle/:fireBody', function(req, res) {

      var year1 = req.params.yyear;
      var month1 = (req.params.mmonth)-1;
      var date1 = req.params.ddate;
      var hours1 = req.params.hhours;
      var minute1 = (req.params.mminute);
      var seconds1 = req.params.sseconds;


      var datetime = new Date((new Date)*1 - 1000*3600*5.5 );


      var responseObject= "Your Function has been set for : "+year1+month1+date1+hours1+minute1+seconds1 +" date "+ datetime;

      var cron = require('node-schedule');
      var date = new Date(year1, month1, date1, hours1, minute1, seconds1);

      cron.scheduleJob(date, function(){

        var request = require("request");

      request("This Function will run" , function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
      });
      });

      res.send(responseObject);

});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Your server *should* run on UTC; if you need to localise datetimes do it client side. What does *"now runs incorrectly"* mean, anyway?

Comment: you want it in your nodejs app level ? or for the environment (if you set here , app would automatically us it i am assuming) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this for your app in heroku

`heroku config:add TZ="America/Los_Angeles"`

http://blog.pardner.com/2012/08/setting-the-default-time-zone-for-a-heroku-app/

Comment: Bro i have seen this before, but i ddint get how to implement it

Comment: Do u have any sample?

Comment: You would need to ssh into your app server then change the timezone from there

Comment: I have done the same in OpenShift , dont know of heroku but as per the sources they seem quite similar , i know that you would have to set this setting on the server (dyno) where your app is running . 
Try to ssh into your app and run the command there .

Comment: Nope Heroku says - Upgrade to paid dynos to configure Heroku SSL
any other Option?

Comment: OH YES, i figured it out

Comment: Thanks! I tried with heroku config:set TZ=Europe/Berlin but my app still does not get the change... maybe it needs some times before the new TZ applies...